# How to automate excel tasks efficiently with xlwings and python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I know that xlwings uses windows COM and stuffs, and based on this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/196776/office-automation-using-visual-c (8th Question):

> A common cause of speed problems with Automation is with repetitive reading and writing of data. This is typical for Excel Automation clients.

And that's exactly what I am doing, tons of reading and writing, and later on I can see that EXCEL.exe is taking up 50% of my CPU usage and my python script has kind of stopped (it just halts there, but python.exe is still on TM).

Now is there anyway to work with this? I asked because, continuing the quote above, Microsoft says:

> However, most people aren't aware that this data can usually be written or read all at once using SAFEARRAY.

So I guess there's a way to work like this on python using xlwings?

Please be noted that: there are things I cant do on other libraries, like "Getting the values on the cells which are visible to the user, all I get is formulas". So I guess xlwings is that way to go. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have experience with xlwings, but from a quick google search, it looks like glorified [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) - a general suggestion would be to read once at the beginning of your script and then only write once at the end, just store everything in between in memory and only write when absolutely necessary

Comment: @wcarhart thanks, but I am planning to distribute this software (freeze first using pyinstaller) and pandas generates too big file sizes which I don't think my clients will appreciate :)

Comment: You just have to send over whole ranges in the form of nested lists instead of assigning single values to single cells, e.g. `mysheet.range('A1').value = [[1,2],[3,4]]`, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#lists

Comment: @FelixZumstein thanks for the comment, but my problem is way bigger than that. I used xlwings because I can get the same values as what the users could see on the EXCEL GUI, but now my problem is performance issues. Now my plan is, instead of getting all those values one-by-one, I thought of putting all those possible values on a variable (so that it will be copied on my address space and I would not need to contantly do RPC calls or stuff) so that I could work directly from my own memory. Yeah, depending on my excel file, memory and CPU usage might vary too, but I guess this is better.

Comment: and then, using a single-line/function again, write it all back to that excel book.

Comment: yes that will work as long as you pass arrays, i.e. nested lists you'll be fine in terms of performance (up to what COM can give you).